# How can I import a js class from a file (like an es module) and ensure it runs first before other js executes?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, node-modules

I have error handling class that listens for errors using `window.addEventListener("error", (event)`, adds the errors to an array field in the class object, and then sends the collected errors to an api endpoint when `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event)` triggers. I need this to be activated before the other code runs in order to catch the errors. My unit tests confirm that the class behaves as expected. I suppose it is possible to just inline all the code but my preference would be to keep the module as a separate file if at all possible, a little extra latency is not a problem. I think need someone with more experience with js to clarify what is possible here and explain how to accomplish my goal as I feel like I'm stuck in the mud of insufficient knowledge.

The problem is that since `<script type='module' src='ErrorReporter.js">` is by nature asynchronous and automatically adds the `defer` attribute this will not run until after some of the other code has run even if it is the first `<script>` tag in the `<head>` of the page and for this reason misses any errors thrown in the code that executes before the error reporter listener is activated.

I've tried:

- Loading it as a module in the script tag as above and then calling it using an inline `<script>`
- Using an import statement in the inline script.
- Creating an async function to load the module dynamically.
- Variations on these themes.

All of these methods have failed for various reasons to catch some errors. Perhaps I am approaching the problem in the wrong way and there is a better solution to monitoring my application for errors, I am still pretty new to js. An ideal solution would to be able to read the errors collected by the browser when `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event)` triggers but this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: A `<script>` imported (without `async` or `defer`) is **synchronous**. No other JavaScript will run before it completes. *edit* Wait, what is it that you think "automatically adds the `defer` attribute"?

Comment: In the documentations for `<script>` adding `type='module'` will automatically make it behave as if the defer flag was added. I've also tried to load it with `<script  src='ErrorReporter.js">` but then it completely fails to load. Perhaps this is because I need to make changes to ErrorReporter.js so it can be loaded without the `type='module'` being set?

Comment: Oh I see, and you have to make it `type=module` because it has to `import` things. Well without knowing more about the script details it's hard to say what the options are. If the error handling code is part of the script, but not dependent on the `import` of some other module, then perhaps that could be split out into an ordinary script to ensure that it runs first. It could even set up a simple version of the facility, which the "real" version with module dependencies could consult upon startup in case any errors have already been caught.

Comment: Also, on a basic philosophical point, the best situation is when you don't have *any* errors from scripts on a page, at least upon initial startup.

Comment: Ha yeah, it would be great to have no errors from scripts on the page but I've had trouble in the past with some users' browsers that just seem to have issues and without a mechanism to identify the specific browser, platform, and error it becomes difficult to know exactly what is going on, how to fix it, and if it should be fixed. 

I think I'm going to try to make the `ErrorReporter.js` a regular js file instead of a module. I think I can make that work and according to your first comment that should run synchronous instead of asynchronous as it does with `type="module"` set.

Comment: Best of luck. If you run into a specific problem you should ask another question :)

Comment: How are you loading and running the "other code" that might throw the errors that you want to catch? Ideally that code should `import` the error handler.

Comment: The error handler is designed for the web browser environment so I am able to take advantage of the events triggered there to catch and log the errors. Once I set the listener up it just catches all of the errors. I can choose if I want the errors to continue and be displayed in the browser console or to hide those errors from the client. Errors that occur in modules will propagate up until caught by the error handler.

Comment: Sure, I was just wondering how are you running your other code? If you're using modules, do you have "main" module as the entrypoint to your application?

Comment: @Bergi The entry point is an HTML file. The modules are loaded with `<script type='module' src='file.js'>` tags and there are two other non-module scripts that load, one that runs code in the `<head>` of the page and another that runs at the end of the `<body>`. These are supported by the modules that do the heavy lifting.

Comment: If you just `import 'ErrorReporter.js';` at the begin of those, before importing anything else, the code that installs the error handlers should always run first

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but that is not true if you use `<script type='module' src='file.js'>` in the html file. In this case the fetching and parsing of the `file.js` occurs asynchronously. Because of this the synchronous scripts that run in the `<head>` and `<body>` may execute before it loads and any error generated there will not be caught.

Comment: Fetching and parsing, yes. Execution, no. If you also want to delay loading, you'd need to use `import('ErrorReporter.js').then(() => import('file.js'))`

Comment: @Bergi Interesting, this isn't my understanding of how loading scripts in an html document works. Please point me to where this behavior is documented. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really need to load your script as a module (`type=module` in the `<script>` tag), you can leave that off and the script will be loaded and run before the browser even proceeds with building the DOM.  If you do need to do an `import` in the script, then perhaps the part of the script that absolutely needs to run first can be split out into a separate mini-script from the module.

If that's not possible, then maybe some kind of "stop-gap" mini-script can be imported (synchronously, that is, not as a module and not with "defer" etc) that sets up a rudimentary version of the actual facility your main script will implement when it is eventually loaded

Finally, and with the caveat that this isn't my area of expertise, I think there are ways you can address this kind of situation with server-side "bundler" tools that trace all the `import` and `export` relationships in advance and put together an aggregated script with all of those resolved, which can then be imported as a single old-school script.